# What does speedrun mode do?

Tags: fez

A [new speedrun mode](https://steamcommunity.com/games/224760/announcements/detail/895475072786334383) (`--gotta-gomez-fast`) was the most publicized new feature of the 1.12 patch, but I can't find any details about it online. How does it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It adds a fourth option to the three save slots (called "Speedrun"). It's a separate mode from the main game that adds a stopwatch timer in the top right corner and adds splits (timestamps) for each cube. There is no "saving" in this mode, but a "Reset run" option is added to the game's menu. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P21YHJSTzE4)'s a video of the mode in action.

The feature doesn't appear to speed up any of the game's transitions or loading screens, but it was written to [not count](https://github.com/renaudbedard/fez-1.12-issues/issues/99) loading times that differ between systems. (The feature request mentions requiring singlethreading but that [doesn't appear](https://github.com/renaudbedard/fez-1.12-issues/issues/125#issuecomment-235778407) to have made it to the final.) PC installations should dump the run's split times into `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\FEZ`

[image: cube splits]

[image: sanic]

To enter speedrun mode, use the `--gotta-gomez-fast` flag on startup. On Steam, right-click the game's entry and open its properties to "Set launch options":

[image: --gotta-gomez-fast]